# Selecting text in a popup box using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, select, input, popup

I have a button. When i click that button, a popup CSS box appears having a text field which has some data. I want this data to be selected as soon as the popup box opens. I tried using the .select() function in jquery but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the button :-

```
<div id="copyBox" style="display:inline-block; margin-left: 10px;"> 
    <button class="btn copy-button"  id="obj" data-clipboard-text="Take data from URL and put it here using Jquery" >
        <a href="#openModal" style="color: #fff;">Copy URL</a>
    </button>
</div>
```

And this is the popup box :-

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <span class="poptext">Copy URL to share the link</span>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            <input type="text" id="urlText" style="width:90%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery i am using :-

```
$( "#obj" ).click(function() {
    $("#urltext").select();
});
```

I don't know where i am going wrong. Can anyone help me out in this?jquery

Comment: Your JQuery-selector is wrong. #urltext would be right. Also with select() you try to register an event-handler, which is almost certainly not what you want. The function you're looking for is val().

Comment: explain clearly that you want ..

Comment: When i click on the button, the url in the text box ( the url is coming in the text box) should be selected so that i can just use Ctrl + C to copy that data instead of selecting it manually first and then copying it. Or may be if i just click on the text field, the data gets selected for copying ( exactly like it happens in Google hangouts share link )

Answer (score 1):

you changed id name in jquery.
change **urlText** instead of **urltext**.
It must be case-sensitive

Comment: inside the button the anchor tag is the problem. Remove it and check once.

Comment: Apparently, <a> tag inside a button doesn't work in HTML 5. Its not allowed. So i might have to use windows.location.href instead of using <a> inside the button tag.

Comment: You can use <a> tag outside the button